# DJANGO: QueryDict obj has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am a bit shy. This is my first question here and my English isn't great.

So I made `CreateAdvert` CBV(CreateView) and overrode the 'post' method for it.

I need to update `QueryDict` and append field 'user' to it. But when I am trying to return the context. It says the error in the title.

Views:

```
class CreateAdvert(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateAdvert
    template_name = 'marketapp/createadvert.html'
    context_object_name = 'advert'


    def post(self, request):
        #Because I don't want to give QueryDict 'user' field right from the form, I override the
        #post method here.
        user = User.objects.filter(email=self.request.user)[0].id
        context = self.request.POST.copy()
        context['user'] = user
        return context
```

Forms:

```
class CreateAdvert(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Advertisment
        fields = ['category', 'title',
                  'description', 'image',
                 ]
```

I have tried to cover context with HttpRequest(). It didn't give me a lot of result. but I tried.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/

You should return a response object, and not the `context` dictionary from the `CreateView`:

Like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

From the error: `obj has no attribute 'status_code'` after the return happens django is trying to find `status_code` which is an expected property of an `HttpResponse` object.

Or:

```
    def post(self, request):
        #Because I don't want to give QueryDict 'user' field right from the form, I override the
        #post method here.
        user = User.objects.filter(email=self.request.user)[0].id
        context = self.request.POST.copy()
        service.create_advert(context, user)
        context['user'] = user
        return HttpResponse('ok', status=200)
```

In regards to where/how to set the `context` I think this happens in a different method usually.

```
class CreateAdvert(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateAdvert
    template_name = 'marketapp/createadvert.html'
    context_object_name = 'advert'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.filter(email=self.request.user)[0].id
        context = self.request.POST.copy()
        context['user'] = user
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I found the solution on Nov 18. So we need to use form_valid() and give user to a form like this: form.instance.user = self.request.user.